# TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable when accessing the float elements of a list

Tags: python-3.x

This code

```
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt
import itertools

class MyClass():
    id = itertools.count(start=1)

    def __init__(self, location = None):
        self.id = next(MyClass.id)
        self.location = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(1, 2)).tolist()[0]


    def __iter__(self):
        for _ in self.__dict__.values():
            yield _

    def f(self, obj):
        return sqrt((self.location[0][0] - obj.location[0][0]) ** 2 + (self.location[0][1] - obj.location[0][1]) ** 2)

    def g(self, objs):
        flag = True
        for obj in objs:
            if self.f(obj) > 0.8:
                flag = False
                break
        return flag

def do():
    objs = []
    first_obj = MyClass()
    objs.append(first_obj)
    counter = 1
    while counter != 10:
        next_obj = MyClass()
        if next_obj.g(objs):
            objs.append(next_obj)
            counter = counter + 1
    return objs

objs = do()
```

returns

```
return sqrt((self.location[0][0] - obj.location[0][0]) ** 2 + (self.location[0][1] - obj.location[0][1]) ** 2)
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

But I don't understand why because `location` here is a list of two elements (One may note the `tolist()` function applied to `location` in the constructor of `MyClass` class.). So, why isn't OK to access its elements by `[.][.]` syntax?

Comment: the location maybe np.random.uniform(0,1,size = (2,2))[0] instead of np.random.uniform(0,1,size=(1,2))[0] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your accessing `location` is a list and it's a single array list rather not a 2D List from where you can't subscribable and can't access like `location[0][0]` or `location[0][1]`. Do you instead use like `location[0]` and `location[1]`

```
def f(self, obj):
    print(self.location)
    print(obj.location)
    return sqrt((self.location[0] - obj.location[0]) ** 2 + (self.location[1] - obj.location[1]) ** 2)
```

Output

```
[0.7281687101439013, 0.972072020630831]
[0.8743260151470964, 0.3612891339626867]

----------------------------------------

[0.8608823868671358, 0.8073941973113157]
[0.3413812202951577, 0.5149064923284026]
```